# Quick Question With UIView's Frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a UIView that I'm using as a subView of the main UIView.

This is what it looks like:

I need to do something like this, but I can't get the coordinates right.  Any ideas?

`[myTableViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.frame.size.width, 1000)];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
myTableViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0.,40.,self.view.fazer.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-40.);
```